# Adding input to a string with a max of 10 words C#

Tags: c#, string, for-loop, if-statement, increment

I am creating for my studies a program a simple one. In this program I need to make a sentence of 10 words. After the last input however I want to make it stop. So what I tried is this: 
Create an empty string called textt, use a while loop since I make it always true it will proceed, create a string with the assignement that shows up in the program to the user aSentence its called, take an int named count and give it the value of 0, then I start my for loop I use the for loop cause I can add a condition and iterator so it stops and of course the initializer.

In the for loop I: print out the aSentence ( the user will read this ), I put a string called input and let the user put in a word ( I'm a beginner I do not know if how to make an error if the user put two words but thats not the assignment now ), I put the string textt since they are immutable but not in here and I add " " for create empty space and of course the input. Then I print out the textt what the user wrote down and I increment ( if I say this correctly ) with i++.

Then I start an if statement which says that if i ( see my for loop ) is equal == to 9 cause I increment this in my for loop it should print out End of the sentence, show the whole textt and then break.

However for some reason the loop is infinite everytime you input something. And the line End of the sentence will show up now and then and now when the loop should be finished at 9. 
My question how do I fix this to make sure the sentencenends when 10 words have been inputted by the user and the End of the sentence pops up at exactly 10 input words.

```
using System;

namespace Opgave_10_woorden_invoegen_in_1_string_plakken
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Create a program that stops after input of 10 words
            string textt = "";
            while (true)
            {
                string aSentence = new string("We are making a sentence of 10 words.");
                int count = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(aSentence);
                    string input = Console.ReadLine();
                    textt = textt + " " + input;
                    Console.WriteLine(textt, i++);
                    if (i == 9)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("End of the sentence", textt);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `while(true)` will run forever (unless some code calls `break`). Your inner `for` loop should work fine - why not just remove the `while` loop?

Comment: Also, you don't need to do call a string constructor for the string assignement (does that even compile?). Just assign the string directly: `string aSentance = "We are making a sentence of 10 words.";`

Comment: There's also a problem in that you're incrementing `i` twice: once in the `for` statement iterator and again in the body of the `for` loop, so `i` will become `9` in only 5 iterations. Remove the inner increment.

Comment: And your for loop condition should be `< 10`, since you want `10` items and the count is starting at `0`. And you don't need a `break` statement inside a `for` loop, since the condition is built-in at the `for` statement.

Comment: The check for _if (i == 9)_ is useless because when i == 9 you have already exited the loop

Comment: Finally, you might look at the documentation for [`Console.WriteLine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline?view=netframework-4.8). The second variable you're passing to it isn't likely what you think it should be.

Comment: Will do much better in your studies if you learn [how to debug programs](https://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/).

Answer (score 1):

Combining my comments into an answer:

1. `while(true)` will run forever (unless some code calls `break`). Your inner `for` loop should work fine - why not just remove the `while` loop?
2. And your for loop condition should be `< 10`, since you want `10` items and the count is starting at `0`. And you don't need a `break` statement inside a `for` loop, since the condition is built-in at the `for` statement.
3. There's also a problem in that you're incrementing `i` twice: once in the for statement iterator and again in the body of the for loop, so `i` will become `9` in only `5` iterations. Remove the inner increment. See the `for` statement documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/for).
4. Also, you don't need to do call a string constructor for the string assignment (does that even compile?). Just assign the string directly: `string aSentance = "We are making a sentence of 10 words.";`
5. Finally, you might look at the documentation for [`Console.WriteLine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline?view=netframework-4.8). The second variable you're passing to it isn't likely what you think it should be.

To put this all into a sample:

```
static void Main()
{
    //Create a program that stops after input of 10 words
    string textt = "";
    string aSentence = "We are making a sentence of 10 words.";

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(aSentence);
        textt = textt + " " + Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine(textt);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("End of the sentence");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much :) it helped me as a beginner because I need to understand this language.

Answer (score 0):

You `while (true)` statement means that your loop runs forever.

You are trying to break out of this by using `break`.  But as this is executed inside an inner `for` loop, then it will only break out of that inner loop and not your outer `while` loop, which is what you intend and expect.

You have no need for the outer while loop, so simply removing it will solve the problem.

If you want 10 inputs then you also need to change your `for` loop to run for 10 iterations, not 9 as your currently have.

Also, you should use StringBuilder class when concatenating strings together so many times, as it is more efficient.
See:  https://www.dotnetperls.com/stringbuilder  for more details

Comment: `StringBuilder` won't make any noticeable difference in this case. See: [the sad tragedy of micro optimization theater](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater/) for more info!

Comment: I agree that it is not the problem in this case, and that one can try to optimise unnecessarily, but as he is learning then StringBuilder is a good class to learn about and helps to adopt good practice early on which is more likely to stick.